# bash to automate file processing

Tags: bash, automation

I need to split a big sorted file into smaller chunks, each file contains a list of sorted person names. Now I want to guarantee that person with same name will not appear in two files, for example,

```
File1:
.
.
James
James
Kobe

File2:
Kobe
Nash
Nash
.
.
```

I need to make it to

```
File1:
.
.
James
James
Kobe
Kobe

File2:
Nash
Nash
.
.
```

Previously I do this manually using sed. Now I want to write a bash script to automate this, but not familiar with the bash.. Any help how to do it?

Comment: What commands did you use to do it manually?  Put those commands in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the last line of the "current" file with the first line of the "next" file. I assume your files are named "File1, File2, ... FileN". This is untested.

```
n=1
while true; do
    current=File$n
    next=File$((++n)) 
    if [[ ! -f $next ]]; then
        break
    fi
    last=$(tail -1 "$current")
    first=$(head -1 "$next")
    while [[ $last == $first ]]; do
        echo "$last" >> "$current"    # append the name to the end of the current
        sed -i 1d "$next"             # remove the first line of the next file
        first=$(head -1 "$next")
    done
done
```

This may be kind of slow because you may be repeatedly remove a single line from the next file. This might be a bit faster: again, untested.

```
n=1
while true; do
    current=File$n
    next=File$((++n)) 
    if [[ ! -f $next ]]; then
        break
    fi
    last=$(tail -1 "$current")
    first=$(head -1 "$next")
    num=$(awk -v line="$last" -v N=0 '$0 == line {N++; next} {print N; exit}' "$next")
    if (( num > 0 )); then
        for (( i=1; i<=num; i++ )); do
            echo "$last" >> "$current"
        done
        sed -i "1,$Nd" "$next"
    fi
done
```